# Как подключить другие языки в Moment.js?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как подключить другие языки в Moment.js? Из документации не все ясно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из коробки только английский. Как прикрутить любой другой написано в доке: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/